# An angle is not being calculated correctly in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In the following diagram, the measure of angle A is about 53 degrees. Precisely, it is 180 - arccos(-3/5). I have a circular arc with its vertex at A drawn with the following command.

```
\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_CAP, draw=blue] let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)} in ($(A)!0.7cm!(P)$) arc (0:\n1:0.7);
```

So, I would think that the following command would have drawn an angle bisector at A.

```
\draw[name path=a_ray_from_A_bisecting_angle_CAP] let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)}, \n2={1/2*\n1} in (A) -- (\n1:1);
```

It does not. Why is the angle bisector not being drawn correctly with this code?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}




\section{Introduction}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path ({(1/4)*2*9*(-3/5)},0) coordinate (A) (0,0) coordinate (B) ({(1/4)*9*(-3/5)},{(1/4)*9*(4/5)}) coordinate (C)
({(1/4)*10},0) coordinate (P);
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(P) +(0,-0.15)$){$P$};
\draw (A) -- (P) -- (C) -- cycle;




%The angle indicating the measure of \angle{CAP} is drawn.
\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_CAP, draw=blue] let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)} in ($(A)!0.7cm!(P)$) arc (0:\n1:0.7);
\draw[name path=a_ray_from_A_bisecting_angle_CAP] let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)}, \n2={1/2*\n1} in (A) -- (\n2:1);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just missing a `+` sign in front of the end coordinate of the line to set it relative to the start coordinate of the path.

While `(X) -- (30:2)` would draw a line from coordinate `X` to the *absolute* polar coordinate at `30:2` (relative to the origin at `0:0`), `(X) -- +(30:2)` draws a line to the coordinate *relative* to the previous coordinate, which is what you want here:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \path 
        ({(1/4)*2*9*(-3/5)},0) coordinate (A) 
        (0,0) coordinate (B) 
        ({(1/4)*9*(-3/5)},{(1/4)*9*(4/5)}) coordinate (C)
        ({(1/4)*10},0) coordinate (P);
        
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize] 
        at ($(A)+(0,-0.15)$) {$A$};
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize] 
        at ($(C)+(0,0.15)$) {$C$};
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize] 
        at ($(P)+(0,-0.15)$) {$P$};
        
    \draw (A) -- (P) -- (C) -- cycle;
    
    %The angle indicating the measure of \angle{CAP} is drawn.
    \draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_CAP, draw=blue] 
        let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)} in 
        ($(A)!0.7cm!(P)$) arc[start angle=0, end angle=\n1, radius=0.7];
    \draw[name path=a_ray_from_A_bisecting_angle_CAP] 
        let \n1={180-acos(-3/5)}, \n2={1/2*\n1} in 
        (A) -- +(\n2:1);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That edit does get the line segment drawn correctly. I thought that A was at the origin.

Comment: @user74973 Actually, `B` is at the origin, but you never use it ... =)